# How to create a new list based on the null values of a data frame and list of values?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, null, row

I have a data frame and list `op` like below.

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Age': [20, np.nan, 19, np.nan]}  
df1=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1)
Name    Age
Tom     20.0
Joseph  NaN
Krish   19.0
John    NaN
op=[1,2]
```

Now I want to create create a new list based on the column `'age'`. If the column `age` has a value then the new list `li` should append `op` first value and if the column `age` has a `null` then the new list should append the value at that position as null. How can I achieve this?
Though I tried to loop through every row to create list but the output is wrong and it takes a loot of time to run as I am lopping through every row.

```
li=[]    
for k in range(len(df1)) :
    if df1.loc[k,'Age']== np.nan:
        print('i')
        li.append(np.nan)
    else:
        for j in op:
            li.append(j)
print(li)
```

output:- `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`

Execpted output:-

```
[1,np.nan,2,np.nan]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the size of `op` is necessarily that of the non-nan values of Age:

```
s = df1['Age'].copy()
op=[1,2]
s[s.notna()] = op
out = s.to_list()
```

output: `[1.0, nan, 2.0, nan]`